# Ruby to_s isn't converting integer to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to convert some values in a hash into a string but the type stays the same.

```
recommended_stores = []
results['data'].each do |stores_list|
  stores_list['stores'].each do |store|
    store['id'].to_s
  end
  recommended_stores << stores_list['stores']
end
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You calculate a string value with `store['id'].to_s`, but you don't assign it anywhere, so it gets lost. You kind of tell Ruby: _Convert the integer to a string, and then throw away the string!_

Answer (score 4):

the method `#to_s` just returns the element converted to a string, but does not actually convert the element to a string permanently. instead of using `#each`, you could use `#map`, like this.

```rb
results['data'].map do |stores_list|
  stores_list['stores'].each do |store|
    store['id'] = store['id'].to_s
  end
end
```

That would return an array of arrays, if you want it to be just one array you can use `#flat_map`.

Comment: This actually returns a 2D array of strings and I want to keep each object but I see your point. Thank you! @vaporyhumo

Comment: Yup, I totally did not try to run it, but I was sure you were gonna get it still. Have a nice day m8.

Answer (score 1):

you got everything but you are not storing it, i think assigning the value of hash with the value.to_s would work, can you try as below

```
recommended_store = []
results['data'].each do |stores_list|
    stores_list['stores'].each do |store|
        store['id'] = store['id'].to_s
    end
    recommended_store << stores_list['stores']
end
```

Note :  in your question array declared is "recommended_store" and last line you are pushing elements in to "recommended_stores" hope its just a typo, and not the cause of problem :-)

Comment: totally a typo - nice catch